# could not derive type of path parameter "id" because it is untyped and obtaining queryset from the viewset failed

Tags: django-rest-framework, swagger, swagger-ui, drf-spectacular

could not derive type of path parameter "id" because it is untyped and obtaining queryset from the viewset failed. Consider adding a type to the path (e.g. int:id) or annotating the parameter type with @extend_schema. Defaulting to "string".

This warning occurred while using the drf-spectacular package for the swagger documentation.

During the debug i found there is missing type for the id that we are passing in request except get request.it says that pass type of the id we are passing in the url.
Is there any way to pass type of id with the url in drf router?

I have tried using urlpatterns instead of using router by spitting url for the get request & for the retrieve, put,patch,delete.

Is there any better way to fix this warning?

Comment: How did you declare your url so far ?

Comment: @Viper 
url defined  with in router

app_name = 'api'
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('user', UserVs, basename='user')

Comment: And did you try to type the id field with @extend_schema ? Because if your problem only occurs in the doc generation, that seems the best thing to do

Comment: Yes i have tried that too. doesn't fix warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the same warning. I fixed it with the below code. (Note that `OpenApiParameter` will need a name, type, and location for this to work.)

```
@extend_schema(
        request=YourSerializerOrNone,
        responses=YourSerializerOrNone,
        parameters = [OpenApiParameter(name="id", type=str, location=OpenApiParameter.PATH)]
    )
```